# xib files layout distorts every time I change anything in it

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout, storyboard

My xib files layout distorts and and comes in place at every alternate action on it. (Action can be resize view, change text in anylabel or anything).

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you using stack views?

Comment: @SahilKapoor Yes